# CompositeComponent Primefaces Dialog appendTo ="@(body)" not working

Tags: primefaces, dialog, modal-dialog, composite-component

I'm using PF 5.1.5 and made some composite components with dialogs which all should be modal and appended to body (so the dialog is really modal). This works when I use dialogs in plain pages, but not if I use them in composite components. I think because the @(body) tag references to the composite component itself? Anyone got a solution?